# Training both positive and negative data with naive bayesian classification?

Tags: classification, naive-bayes

This might not be the best forum for this question so please forgive me.

So I was demo'ed a custom naive bayesian classifier that accepted both positive & negative training data. An example:

"I am really excited about getting my python tonight"

This would be trained as positive on the class "pets", "happy" but negative against "python", "programming"

This dramatically increased how quickly a class could be trained accurately.

So my question: is this really naive bayesian classification? Is there anything else out there like this?

Additional information: The classifier didn't just return a single matching class against input but returned an array of classes and their "scores"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is this a naive Bayesian classifier (so far as I understand your description), but it's a general rule that naive Bayes needs both positive and negative examples in its training data in order to perform well. A spam filter should have known examples of non-spam as well as known examples of spam.

Comment: Yes but traditionally the classifier would then have a "spam" and "not spam" class right? This system only had a "pets" and "programming" class. Maybe some magic behind the scenes? I have looked at multiple machine learning frameworks/libs that offer naive bayesian classification and haven't find an example that works like this. In traditional systems to train something as "not programming" you would simply train as "pets" but all training is "positive" in to the class your training against.

Comment: In other words for each class in the classifier you can answer "yes" or "no" given a piece of training data. Nearly every system/implementation I've seen only allows you to train "yes" not "no" against a class.

Comment: @Kylee I can't speak authoritatively about software when I don't know what the software is, of course, but it sounds like this program is doing classification for each of several variables (e.g., "pets", "python", and "programming") and not mentioning that each variable corresponds to two classes (e.g., "belongs to 'pets'" and "does not belong to 'pets'"). Or you may be confusing the dependent variable with the independent variables.

Comment: "I can't speak authoritatively about software when I don't know what the software is" I figured this would be the answer. I don't think this is the case. The best analog I've been able to create is a set of classifiers, each with a positive and negative class. So the python classifier would have "python" and "not python" classes. Then multiple classifiers are compared based on the scores of their "on topic" and "off topic" classes.

Comment: I wish I had a better example but I don't have access to the source of this classifier I'm referring too.

Comment: @Kylee "The best analog I've been able to create is a set of classifiers, each with a positive and negative class" That would be my best guess of what the mystery program does. The "score" for each variable and example would be the probability that the example belongs to the positive class for that variable.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me some direction and that makes sense.